# Display Rails check box to be either checked or unchecked based on the value in the database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've tried everything.

I am new to rails and trying to build a simple app that displays a list of todo items. Each item has a check box that gets saved to a boolean column in the database called `done`. When editing the task and marking it as checked, the check box is marked appropriately. But when I go to the `index` page, which is setup to list all todo items, the check boxes remain unchecked no matter what the value is in the database.

Here is `edit.html.erb`

```
<div class="item">
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>

    <%= f.check_box :done %>
    <%= f.label :content, "Task" %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>

    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn submit" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Here is `index.html.erb`

```
<%= render 'layouts/new' %>

<ul class="items">
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <li>
    <%= check_box_tag 'done', item.done %>
    <%= item.content %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_item_path(item) %> | 
    <%= link_to "Delete", item, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :title => "Delete item"%>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the third value is the checked.
So,

```
<%= check_box_tag 'done', '1', item.done %>
```

1 is the value the third item is the checked value

Comment: That did it. Thank you. I knew I was close, but missing something. Thank you for teaching me something today.